# renReturn type as same class Object in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have this class

```
public class Child extends Parent
{
    private Child name;
    public Child addToParent(int num)
    {
        name = new Child();
        name+num;
        return name;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make the function return a Child object. Unfortunately, I can't pick a different return type because I'm assigned to do so. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What is it you intended with `name+num;`?

Comment: Can u elaborate your question please. What do you mean by " I can't pick a different return type because I'm assigned to do so. "

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm trying to receive a number and add it to the child object.

Comment: @Luther West . I doubt name+num is the right syntax in the above code

Comment: @Kumar It's a homework assignment and I grinded my head going around trying to return a Child object from a function in the Child class. I tried everything I could and if it doesn't give me compiler errors, it throws cast exceptions at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

```
    This is the best I can derive from your code.I am not sure what your trying to do. But this Will avoid your error.
    public class Child extends Parent {
    public String name = "";
    public Child addToParent(int num) {
   Child child = new Child(); 
    child.name = child.name + num;
    return child; } }
```